# Everything is correct but still my scrollView is not scrolling?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

Its very common for we all to use UIScrollView i have taken the one on xib, and have set its all properties well, It was scrolling at start but latter on i put one more view in it and it stopped to scroll,

```
[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(containerViewOfRecurrence.frame.size.width, 1000)];
scroll.pagingEnabled = NO;
scroll.delegate      = self;
scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
scroll.clipsToBounds = YES;

[scroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

I have added the delegate method to detect the scroll,

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"%f", scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

and which does not get called on scrolling.

Here are the images of xib

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many views are you adding to it ?

Comment: please post code how to add view in uiscrollview

Comment: First check `File's Owner` you properly connect with XIB and also put **@property** and **@synthesize** them >>?

Comment: @IronManGill should i add the images here,

Comment: @Rushabh I have not added the view programmatically i have added it from xib, statically.

Comment: @iPatel as i said it was scrolling well, but as soon as i added one more view or though i do some changes in scroll view and again add it to view it just stops to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

When you add your other new `UIView` *(custom view)* at that time you also need to change `contentSize` of `UIScrollView`.

such like,

After add `UIView`.

```
[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(containerViewOfRecurrence.frame.size.width, scroll.contentSize.height + myCustomeView.frame.size.height)]
```

Comment: i have added the image of scroll view from xib, befor the custome view there are other controls too,

Answer (score 0):

I got it, its the iOS 6 problem, as in iOS 6 the content size is calculated automatically , we do not need to set it programmatically useAutoLayout calculates it, and along with that, we need to one property named translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO.

I added the UIEdgeInsetsMake by some size so that to get more scroll,

finally this is my working code

```
//[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(containerViewOfRecurrence.frame.size.width, 1000)];
scroll.pagingEnabled = NO;
scroll.delegate      = self;
scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
scroll.clipsToBounds = YES;

[self.scroll setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 300, 0)];

self.scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints= NO;

[scroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```